# Error when adding vue http header

Tags: go, cors, vue.js

I have a working application with a front end in `vuejs` and a backend in `go`. I'm in the process of adding the final features to the authentication and I'm running into an error.

When I try to add any http header to the `vuejs` request I get an error.

This is what I'm adding to the `vue component`:

```
http: {
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer 123'
  }
}
```

And I'm getting a `preflight` error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/api/investments?limit=6. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Now I know this is usually a server side problem but I am adding the response header `resp.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")`. `cors`. If I remove the the http property in the `vue object` everything works fine. Its pretty bizzare I even tried handling the `OPTIONS` request with `go` but my handler for the api doesn't even get hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the answer it is a server problem the `Authorization` header was not authorized. So just add it as a middleware to allow for it.

```
c := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedHeaders: []string{"Origin", "Accept", "Content-Type", "Authorization"},
    })
handler := c.Handler(router)
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", handler))
```

I am using the `rs/cors` package

Comment: @holys I gotta wait 2 days

Comment: Note that, contrary to popular belief, listing `Origin` as an allowed header is never required.